# "I am machine" without an article?

Tags: grammar, articles, zero-article

I have a question about lyrics of a song **"I Am Machine"** by Three Days Grace.

I mentioned that they used no article in this song. Is it grammatically okay to say "I am machine" without an article and why?

Comment: If you can say *I am human* you can also say *I am machine*. It's being used as a mass noun rather than a countable noun.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in the example *I am human*, the word *human* is not a noun (or a mass noun). It's an adjective.

Comment: _Purists long objected to human as a shortened form of human being, but today it’s so pervasive—even in formal writing—that it should be accepted as standard._ Garner's Modern American Usage 3rd Ed.

Comment: @MvLog yes, but is "I am human being" any better?

Comment: @MichaelRybkin I'm not sure what I was thinking when I made the first comment. The first part is true, but *human* (or *machine*) certainly is being used as an adjective in that context. (Although it's interesting that we say that only because there *isn't* an article used and we assume it's not just a mistake.)

Comment: Perhaps Floyd welcomed you to machine a few times too often, @Jason?  It's all right.  We know where you've been.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not one hundred percent sure about this, I think the reason why there is no indefinite article in front of *machine* (normally, it's a noun and there should be one) has to do with the fact that what they're doing is they're trying to use the noun *machine* as an adjective akin to how the word [**human**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/human) can be used as an adjective to mean *exhibiting qualities that are characteristic of people as opposed to God, animals or machines, especially in being susceptible to weaknesses*. For instance, when people say:

> I make mistakes because **I'm only human**.

What they're saying is we as humans are flawed and susceptible to making mistakes because we're not perfect beings like gods or robots (robots are perfect in that they're not supposed to make mistakes). This is, of course, different from situations when you say it with an article: *I'm a human*. When you say that, you're simply stating the fact that you are a member of the class of humans as opposed to being a member of other classes of living as well as nonliving things such as dogs or books.

So, they're just trying to be creative with their language:

> I wish I could feel something, but I'm only machine.